# How do I run a SQL query via REST against QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I'm using Python for some tests and I would like to be able to run a SQL query via REST. Is there an easy way to use requests to run queries like:

```py
requests.get('http:myserver:9000/exec' query="select * from my_table")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use REST via Python, this can be done similar to the following example:

```py
import requests
import json

host = 'http://myserver:9000'

sql_query = "select * from my_table limit 100"
query_params = {'query': sql_query}

try:
  response = requests.post(host + '/exec', params=query_params)
  json_response = json.loads(response.text)
  rows = json_response['dataset']
  for row in rows:
    print(row)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
  print("Error: %s" % (e))
```

There is additional documentation for this on the [QuestDB REST docs page](https://questdb.io/docs/develop/query-data#rest-api)